# Multidimensional Array loads very slow php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to create a multidimensional array for a Menu where the seccond array represents de submenu (subcategory). The thing is it is working okay but it loads very slow and I would appreciate some help to find a better and maybe cleaner solution that loads faster.

The function I am using is the next function:

```
public function getMenu() {
    $result  = $this->db->FetchArrayAll("SELECT ml . * , m.icon, m.body_position FROM menu AS m inner JOIN menu_language AS ml ON m.id = ml.id_menu AND ml.id_language ='".$this->id_lenguage."' WHERE m.body_position = '".$this->body_position."' ORDER BY m.position");
    $retorno  = array();
    foreach ($result as $r) {
        $submenu  = $this->db->FetchArrayAll("SELECT sl . * , s.icon, s.name, s.position FROM submenu AS s inner join submenu_language AS sl ON s.id = sl.id_submenu AND sl.id_language ='".$this->id_lenguage."' WHERE s.id_menu ='".$r['id_menu']."' ORDER BY s.position");
        $retorno[] = array( 
          "id" => $r['id_menu'], 
          "icon" =>$r['icon'],
          "name" => $r['menu'],
          "body" => $r['body_position'],
          "submenu" => $submenu
        );
    }
    return $retorno;
}
```

`$this->db` represents my database class where FetchArrayAll is a simple function that looks something like this:

```
public function FetchArrayAll($query) {

   $q_query = mysql_query($query);
   $r = array();
   while($q = mysql_fetch_array($q_query)) {
      array_push($r, $q);
   }
   return $r;
}
```

Just wrote it so may contain some errors, but the final function is working okay, anyway I would also appreciate any comments to optimaze any of the functions written.

Comment: suggest you using SQL-JOIN to speed up the process.

Comment: Ok thank you will change both queries with joins hopefully will get faster results

Comment: Changed both queries and still loading really slow, justs edited my question so you can see the final queries, any ideas?

Comment: Profile the query. The code you posted is irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean with profile the query?

Comment: I searched about profiling a query and finished timing my queries, anyway after some other tests i've been able to see I was wrong, its not the queries what makes the page load slow, thank you anyway :D

Comment: To profile a query, you add `EXPLAIN` before `SELECT` statement to check what MySQL does. In your case, it might be that you're simply loading a lot of records, or that you're causing I/O bound operations due to badly set up data model.